# detecting minimum and maximum using matrix calculus

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus

If the first derivative of something is $x^TA+b$ and its second derivative is $A^T$ how do I know for which values of $x$ is minimum or maximum? $x$ is a vector and $A$ is a square matrix.

$A$ is invertible and symmetric.
The original function $f(x) = \frac12 x^TAx+b^Tx$

Comment: It may not have a $\max$ or a $\min$. Take $b=0$, $A= \operatorname{diag} ( 1, -1)$.

Answer (score 1):

The derivative is suppose to be $Ax+b$. Equating to $0$ and solve for $x$ would give us the stationary point.

If $A$ is positive definite, it is a global minimium.

If $A$ is negative definite, it is a global maximum.

Otherwise, it is neither.

Comment: well, first off, isn't derivative of xTAX=2XTA? I saw it in a few matrix calculus handouts online so I am not sure why you say Ax+b and not XTA+b? Also, for the second part how do you prove that? or a link to proof or analogy

Comment: is $b$ a column vector? is $x^TA$ a row vector? a row vector and column vector can't be added together. If A is positive definite, the quadratic function is a convex function, in one dimension think of $f(x)=x^2$. If it is negative defintie, it is a concave function, think of $f(x)=-x^2$. Otherwise, it is a [saddle point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saddle_point)

Comment: b is d*1 same as x. so is my derivative right or is yours right? can you please explain why your derivative is correct?

Comment: If you refer to wikipedia page of [matrix calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus) you can see that there is a numerator layout and a denominator layout, some people prefer to work with row vectors and some prefer column vector. I choose to work with column vectors. $Ax$ and $b$ are both column vectors, hence they can be added. For your case $x^TA$ is a row vector while $b$ is a column vector, hence there is some inconsistency.